# Text wrap around a number 8 symbol

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, text-wrap

me and my project again,

I'm wondering how my design will look if the text follows the curve of the visual anchor of the piece - a 470 pt Helvetica "8".

However, after creating outlines for the symbol(I tried expanding, I guess the feature has the same purpose) and Object>Text Wrap>Make ; the type doesn't conform to the shape.

[image]

Any idea what could be causing this? And possible workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 8 needs to be in the foreground otherwise it won't work.
Or an other option is to manipulate the text frame directly.

[image]

Comment: That's weird, I swear I tried having the 8 on the top of the layer and it didn't work. Might be because of the text I'm using. Thanks!

Comment: Could have been that there are on different layers and 'bring to front' did not actually bring it in front of the text